# Altered fstab - no longer able to SSH or access http

Tags: linux, fstab

I altered the fstab file. I changed udev to dev to try to fix a mounting issue in /dev/sda1 but after I restarted the server, I cannot access it with ping, ssh, smb, or http. Is the issue related to my uneducated fstab change or should I be looking someplace else?

```
  [/Volumes]$ ping 192.168.0.190
  PING 192.168.0.190 (192.168.0.190): 56 data bytes
  Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
  Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
  Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
  Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
  ç^C
  --- 192.168.0.190 ping statistics ---
  5 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss

  21:05:31
  [/Volumes]$ ssh wall
  ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.190 port 22: No route to host

  21:05:34
  [/Volumes]$ ssh wall
  ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.190 port 22: Host is down
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the machine wasn't even started, I guess it failed some where in the initramfs, i.e can't mount root drive.

So any network connection would just fail here, you should take a look physically, I don't think you can solve this remotely.

Comment: Hey warl0ck, thanks for the reply. It looks like it's running but I have no monitor to verify or anything. I'm rocking one if these: [Dreamplug](http://www.globalscaletechnologies.com/t-dreamplugdetails.aspx)

Comment: @slowBear if the storage is removable, you can mount it on another machine and revert your fstab changes.

Comment: @jordanm thanks for the tip - I dont think the storage is removable though :/

Comment: @slowBear then boot with external media